# Working with Facebook.Winforms.dll

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-graph-api

I downloaded a project from Code project named '**FacebookDemonstration**' and this project has a refrence to *facebook.dll* and *facebook.Winforms.dll*. In Facebook.Winforms we have a control Named FacebookService that i added to my form with name 'fbService'.

```
fbService.ApplicationKey = "1234567891234";

        // Add all needed permissions
        List<Enums.ExtendedPermissions> perms = new List<Enums.ExtendedPermissions>
                                                {
                                                                   Enums.ExtendedPermissions.email,Enums.ExtendedPermissions.user_photo
                                                                };

        fbService.ConnectToFacebook(perms);
```

Firstly Facebook login page appears and after login in last line I have this error:

**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

Unbelievably in first try the application worked and the permission page appears but after that only error.

Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is true, but this library is outdated and in facebook many things have changed.